# how to implement jtable in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i trying to implement table by jtable and done this step:

1- install it from nuget by Install-Package jTable

2- create view by this :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<link href="/Scripts/jtable/themes/standard/blue/jtable_blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jtable/external/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>*@
<input id="Load" type="button" value="load" />

<div id="PersonTable">

</div>
<script>
    $(Load).click(function () {
        debugger;
        $("#PersonTable").jtable({
            title: 'teacherlist',
            actions: {
                listAction:'/Teacher/personlist',
                deleteAction: '/Home/DeletePerson',
                updateAction: '/Home/UpdatePerson',
                createAction: '/Home/CreatePerson'
            },
            fields: {
                Name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '15%'
                }
            }
        });

        $(PersonTable).jtable('load');
    });
</script>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

this is my layout references:

```
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

but when i debug jquery code i receive this error

jTable - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jtable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. I would start by referencing jquery and jquery-ui dependencies in the Layout:

```
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

and then inside the view ensure that all scripts have been placed in the proper section:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<input id="Load" type="button" value="load" />

<div id="PersonTable"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <link href="~/scripts/jtable/themes/standard/blue/jtable_blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jtable/external/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Load').click(function () {
            debugger;
            $("#PersonTable").jtable({
                title: 'teacherlist',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '@Url.Action("personlist", "Teacher")',
                    deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeletePerson", "Home")',
                    updateAction: '@Url.Action("UpdatePerson", "Home")',
                    createAction: '@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Home")'
                },
                fields: {
                    Name: {
                        title: 'Name',
                        width: '15%'
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#PersonTable').jtable('load');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help it created but can't load data and show this error message `An error occurred while communicating to the server.`

Comment: It looks like there' some issue with the server side part that needs to return the data. Did you check if the `Teacher/personlist` action is working? Look at the network tab in your browser to see what request is being sent to the server. Then you could inspect the error message.